# Get current username on windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I modified my username in Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Change Your Name.

But when I use the `GetUserName` function, it returned my old username.

How do I get the new one?

**EDIT 1**

Here's the code as requested:

```
char user[UNLEN + 1];
DWORD user_len = UNLEN + 1;
GetUserName(user, &user_len);
```

Comment: did it still return your old username even after logging off and logging on with the new username?

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: @EdChum I modified it long ago

Comment: When you changed your username did it actually change it on disk, i.e. is the string you're getting back still the path in C:\Users\ ? (I don't know how Windows deals with that.)

Comment: @Rup it's still the old one

Comment: What do you want to do with the user name?

Answer (score 5):

Try to use the API [GetUserNameEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724435(v=vs.85).aspx), and passing as a format `NameDisplay`. I guess you changed the display name of the user, not the logon name.